# Showing that Klein-Gordon wave equation is relativistic?

Tags: special-relativity, waves, klein-gordon-equation

Using normalized constants, the classical wave equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} 
\end{equation}

differs from the Klein-Gordon wave equation by

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} - m^2\psi
\end{equation}

The Klein-Gordon [2] wave equation is also said to be relativistic. This implies that the classical [1] wave equation is *not* relativistic.

What is meant by a "relativistic" wave, and what specifically can we *measure* from the wave itself that tells whether this wave is relativistic or not?

Is there a specific motion path in 1D for which the classical wave [1] does *not* appear the same as for the stationary observer's reference frame at $x=0$?

Comment: Any classical wave equation where the wave velocity is $c$ (and you don't have weird non-invariant extra terms) is Lorentz-invariant, and therefore "relativistic" in my book.

Comment: *This implies…* What is your logic for concluding that? Do you understand that “being relativistic” means “being form-invariant under Lorentz transformations”? Both equations have this property.

Comment: Your final paragraph implies that you think solutions of relativistic wave equations look the same to all inertial observers. This is not the case. The Doppler shift of light is an example. Observers with relative motion observe a different frequency and wavelength when observing the same light wave.

Comment: I recommend using the Lorentz transformation of coordinates to work out how the combination of second derivatives in both equations transforms.

Comment: @Ghoster thank you. it seems i misunderstood the comparison is to Schrodinger wave equation, which is non-relativistic, not to the classical wave equation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the "intuitive" derivation from quantum mechanics books:
$$
E^2=\mathbf{p}^2c^2 + m^2c^4
$$
Quantization is
$$
E\rightarrow i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\mathbf{p}\rightarrow-i\hbar\nabla,$$
so the energy-momentum relation becomes
$$
-\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial t^2}=-\hbar^2\nabla^2\psi + m^2c^4\psi \leftrightarrow
\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\psi + \frac{m^2c^4}{\hbar^2}\psi
$$

If we performed the same operations with non-relativistic dispersion relation
$$E=\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m},$$
we would get the Schrödinger equation for free particle.

Comment: so the energy is either correct/incorrect relativistically. Is there also something physically/observably wrong when a wave is not relativistic?

Comment: @James on more serious level, Klein Gordon is invariant to lorentz transformations, whereas Schrödinger is not - all the usual differences between relativistic and not are there.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question considering I have no knowledge about the subject but, how do squares in eq 1 become second-order derivatives in eq 3?

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist Squaring an operator means applying it twice. The operator here is “take a derivative”. Applying this twice gives a second derivative.

Comment: @Ghoster like taking the divergence of a gradient?

Comment: It’s similar but not as complicated. This is just $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\psi$.